# How to prevent multiple classes for the same business object?

Tags: oop, code-duplication

A lot of the time I will have a Business object that has a property for a user index or a set of indexes for some data. When I display this object in a form or some other view I need the users full name or some of the other properties of the data. Usually I create another class myObjectView or something similar. What is the best way to handle this case?

To further clarify:
If I had a class an issue tracker and my class for an issue has IxCreatedByUser as a property and a collection of IxAttachment values (indexes for attachment records). When I display this on a web page I want to show John Doe instead of the IxCreatedByUser and I want to show a link to the Attachment and the file name on the page. So usually I create a new class with a Collection of Attachment objects and a CreatedByUserFullName property or something of that nature. It just feels wrong creating this second class to display data on a page. Perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: Couldn't really understand what you want.

Comment: Complexities often cannot be nulled out of existance. What you are doing is making reality a little clearer :-) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The façade pattern.**

I think your approach, creating a façade pattern to abstract the complexities with multiple datasources is often appropriate, and will make your code easy to understand.

Care should be taken to create too many layers of abstractions, because the level of indirection will ruin the initial attempt at making the code easier to read. Especially, if you feel you just write classes to match what you've done in other places. For intance if you have a myLoanView, doesn't necessarily you need to create a myView for every single dialogue in the system. Take 10-steps back from the code, and maybe make a façade which is a reusable and intuitive abstraction, you can use in several places.

Feel free to elaborate on the exact nature of your challenge.

Answer (score 1):

One key principle is that each of your classes should have a defined purpose. If the purpose of your "Business object" class is to expose relevant data related to the business object, it may be entirely reasonable to create a property on the class that delegates the request for the lookup description to the related class that is responsible for that information. Any formatting that is specific to your class would be done in the property.

Comment: I think your mentioning the "SingleResponsibilityPrinciple" here. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle
http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf

I also end up writing a seperate class that is responsible for formatting.  "MyObjectViewHelper" etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's some guidelines to help you with deciding how to handle this (pretty common, IMO) pattern:

1. If you all you need is a quickie link to a lookup table that does not change often (e.g. a table of addresses that links to a table of states and/or countries), you can keep a lazy-loaded, static copy of the lookup table.
2. If you have a really big class that would take a lot of joins or subqueries to load just for display purposes, you probably want to make a "view" or "info" class for display purposes like you've described above.  Just make sure the XInfo class (for displaying) loads significantly faster than the X class (for editing).  This is a situation where using a view on the database side may be a very good idea.